Unexpected error from mypy: Why isn't my type acceptable?
I am getting an error from mypy that I cannot explain (and therefore cannot fix):
build_rag.py:116: error: 
Argument "metadatas" to "add" of "AsyncCollection" 
has incompatible type "list[dict[str, str]]"; 
expected "Mapping[str, str | int | float | bool] | 
list[Mapping[str, str | int | float | bool]] | 
None"  [arg-type]

I am passing a list[dict[str,str]] as detected correctly by mypy. I would have expected this to match against the second of the three expected types: list[Mapping[str, str|int|float|bool]]. I am not the author of the add() function being called. (It is the chromadb.AsyncCollection.add() method.)
Am I being stupid/blind, or should mypy have accepted my input?
The code calling the function is this, with ids and chunks defined earlier. The code variable is already a string; the call to str() was just an act of desperation on my part. The path variable is a pathlib.Path object. chunks is a list[str].
            metadata = {
                "dc.identifier": str(path),
                "code": str(code),
            }
            metadatas = [metadata for chunk in chunks]
            await collection.add(
                ids=ids,
                documents=chunks,
                metadatas=metadatas,
            )

This is the only mypy error flagged in my file so, fingers crossed, the rest of the types are as advertised.

Could you please provide full code. Maybe somewhere above you specifying metadata or metadatas as different type?

I've seen a very similar problem with mypy before. Would be curious to see if this is simply a bug on mypy's side.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

A dict is a MutableMapping, and lists are invariant, so a list of dicts is not a list of Mappings.

Duplicate: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[str]", variable has type "List[Union[str, int]]").

A list[dict[str,str]] isn't a list[Mapping[str, str|int|float|bool]], because you can add a dict[str, float] to a list[Mapping[str, str|int|float|bool]], but you can't add a dict[str, float] to a list[dict[str,str]].
chromadb should probably use Sequence instead of list to annotate sequence arguments they don't need to modify. A list[dict[str,str]] would be a valid Sequence[Mapping[str, str|int|float|bool]], because the Sequence ABC doesn't specify any insertion operations.
In the meantime, you can explicitly annotate your variables differently, overriding the default type inference:
metadata: Mapping[str, str|int|float|bool] = # whatever

